# grant permission to SHOW FIELDS

Tags: mysql, permissions

I create a user to make a dump twice a week  but when I try to execute mysqldump I have this error

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `contabilidad_amortizaciones_completas_por_id_vista`': execute command denied to user 'dump'@'%' for routine 'bbbdd57_antes_del_cambio.calcula_dotacion_acumulada_fc' (1370)
```

The grants to this user are these

```
GRANT SELECT, SHOW DATABASES, LOCK TABLES, EVENT ON *.* TO 'dump'@'%'
```

The funcion call 'bbbdd57_antes_del_cambio.calcula_dotacion_acumulada_fc' have this code:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%'
FUNCTION 
bbbdd57_antes_del_cambio.calcula_dotacion_acumulada_fc(_id_amortizacion int)
RETURNS decimal(10,2)
  BEGIN
    SET @resultado = 0; 
    ( SELECT SUM(R.acumulado) FROM (
             SELECT MAX(`cadm`.`acumulado`) AS `acumulado`,
              cadm.id_amortizacion
              FROM `contabilidad_amortizaciones_detalles_meses` `cadm`
              WHERE ((`cadm`.`id_amortizacion` = _id_amortizacion)
              AND (`cadm`.`contabilizado` = 1))
              GROUP BY `cadm`.`anio_detalle`, `cadm`.`contabilizado`
            ) AS R
         GROUP BY R.id_amortizacion INTO @resultado
    );
 RETURN @resultado;
 END
```

I have other instances with other users-dump with this permissions and I dont have any problem.

Thanks

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Mysql 5.7 version

Comment: Are any `VIEWs` involved?

Comment: No, only tables, procedures and functions. What happen with VIEWS?

Comment: I correct, I have some views

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump
```

will dump the `CREATE VIEW`.  However, it shows it twice.  See the second version for the correct output.

Including the option `--no-data` is optional.

You do need `SHOW VIEW` permissions to when using mysqldump or `SHOW CREATE VIEW`.